# Python IDLE shell restarting

Tags: python, python-idle

When I run my code, it prints out the values I tell it to but it does it rarely.

and majority of the time it restarts the shell after a few seconds.

it just says:
============= RESTART: Shell =============

I try to run the code a few time but it rarely executes it fully.

Comment: What code? Maybe the `print` command isn't actually running because the code is following a different path of execution than you think.

Comment: sometimes it runs what I wanted it to run though.

And I am training a NN with images.

Comment: Then there could be something making your program run in a non-deterministic way. Regardless, we can't help you much with seeing the offending code, unless this is a known problem with IDLE; which I don't know of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IDLE GUI process runs your code in a separate user-code execution process, with a socket connection. When the GUI process loses contact with the execution process, it starts a new execution process and displays the RESTART line to let you know what happened.  The connection loss is nearly always because your code caused python in the execution process to crash and vanish.

You first should run your code without IDLE from a console/terminal/CommandPrompt window and see if it either runs okay or displays some error message before crashing.  Running okay is unlikely but faintly possible.  If it still crashes, you have to debug the problem, which you can do running from an IDLE editor.  For that, read, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, to isolate the problem as much as possible.

Comment: That is very weird why it hasn't crashed or "restarted". I tried 10/10 times to run the same code inside the console and it didn't crash.

I guess it doesn't work in the IDLE shell? thank you for the recommendation.